# Using os.chdir to access a file in which a folder starts with '\f'

Tags: python, string

I know that \f is a form feed. I want to access my folder the following way:

```
os.chdir("C:\Python27\BGT_Python\skills\fuzzymatching")
```

The folder 'fuzzymatching' starts with the \f symbol which breaks the string.

What's the easiest way to get around these types of symbols?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an `r` character in front of the string:

`os.chdir(r"C:\Python27\BGT_Python\skills\fuzzymatching")`

See [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html).

> In triple-quoted strings, unescaped newlines and quotes are allowed (and are retained), except that three unescaped quotes in a row terminate the string. (A ``quote'' is the character used to open the string, i.e. either ' or ".)

and

> Unless an `r' or`R' prefix is present, escape sequences in strings are interpreted according to rules similar to those used by Standard C.

Comment: nice solution. :)

Comment: very nice indeed :>)

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, I'll add:

```
os.chdir("C:/Python27/BGT_Python/skills/fuzzymatching")
```

About the only part of Windows that actually requires backslashes is the command line.

Comment: I actually doesn't require it.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
os.chdir("C:\Python27\BGT_Python\skills\\fuzzymatching")
```

I just added a `\` to scape `\f`.

Comment: nice solution. :)